# Sum column where (condition) with datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

Suppose I have the following datatable, and i want to sum all rows where column is "money" where the month is may.

```
+--------------------+-------+
| Date               | money |
+--------------------+-------+
| 5/3/2020 8:00:00   | 20    |
+--------------------+-------+
| 5/3/2020 11:00:00  | 10    |
+--------------------+-------+
| 8/3/2020 12:00:00  | 5     |
+--------------------+-------+
| 9/7/2020 10:00:00  | 56    |
+--------------------+-------+
| 2/11/2020 13:00:00 | 45    |
+--------------------+-------+
```

Expected result is 30, my code gives 0 as answer

My code is:

```
string data= dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Where(y => y.Field<DateTime>("Date").Month==m)
               .Sum(x => x.Field<int>("money"))
               .ToString();
```

Note, I don't want a sulotion with iteration, but similar to mine (Like sql style "select from where...")

Comment: Can you provide us [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Not reproducible with the data supplied.

Comment: If you want May in a particular year (not just May of any year), you can use `DataTable.Compute` but you're not clear on what you actually want  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My result is 30.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add("money", typeof(int));

var row = dt.NewRow();
row["Date"] = new DateTime(2020, 5, 3);
row["money"] = 20;
dt.Rows.Add(row);

row = dt.NewRow();
row["Date"] = new DateTime(2020, 5, 3);
row["money"] = 10;
dt.Rows.Add(row);

row = dt.NewRow();
row["Date"] = new DateTime(2020, 8, 3);
row["money"] = 5;
dt.Rows.Add(row);

row = dt.NewRow();
row["Date"] = new DateTime(2020, 9, 7);
row["money"] = 56;
dt.Rows.Add(row); 

row = dt.NewRow();
row["Date"] = new DateTime(2020, 2, 11);
row["money"] = 45;
dt.Rows.Add(row);

var sumOfValuesInMarch = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Date").Month == 5)
    .Sum(x => x.Field<int>("money"))
    .ToString(); // 30
```

Comment: I don't know why you post an answer when the question itself has no reproducible errors.

Comment: @Steve i am sure this will guide to a solution